# Where can I find a factory image for the Moto X 2nd Gen 2014?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, factory-image

I went to Motorola's site and requested one, but since it's Sunday, I don't think I will receive the file until tomorrow.

You would think that someone would host the image file somewhere just in Motorola's site went down or something. Is there a place I can download it from other than the manufacturers site that I do not know about?

Answer (score 0):

Email Support.

(No im serious. I couldnt even get mind until I did)